# How can I remove views using vary of traits?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I have a view controller with some nested views in portrait mode, but I need to know if its posible to generate a variation on landscape where I only have one image (deleting all my elements that I have in portrait view) or I need to create another view controller for this case.

Comment: Short answer? Sure you can. However, your question is so vague it's impossible to help you. What have you tried? What *specific* issue are you facing? Do you know which overrides to tap into when orientation changes? When you say "delete", do you mean "hide"? Finally, what about when a user **returns** from landscape to portrait?

Comment: Sorry, I need to show a register form with a labels and textfields in portrait and in landscape i only need an image, its posible create a variation and delete these controls to only have a image ?, or I need to create a viewcontroller for each case

Answer (score 3):

you can change that in code using `traitcollection`

**For your case**

you can use below condition which presents `landscape` orientation

```
if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {   
    labelName.isHidden = true  // hide label
    textfield.isHidden = true // hide text
    imageName.isHidden = false  // unhide image
}
```

Note: you have also `traitcollection.horizontalSizeClass` and it can be `.compact` or `.regular` according to which orientation of the device you want to edit and the type of device you are working on.

[traitcollection options for different devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GydXq.png)